# Trying to append an image in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, function, webview

So ive been trying to find the simplest way to append an image in a webview using javascript. i wrote out the html myself and included my own function that looked something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function image(src) {
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = src;
    document.getElementById('image').appendChild(img);
}
</script>
```

I found out that i cant just use 
    myview.loadurl(javascript:image('line1.png'));
So im trying to figure out how i can do this. I was thinking about relegating this function to one line of code i can fit in loadurl(), but i seem to be getting an error around that as well. Ive heard of using addJavascriptInterface but its seems complex and im not sure if it fits what i want. So whats my best course of action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is so simple. Try the following

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class StackOverFlowActivity extends Activity {

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView view=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
        view.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "Android");
    }

    final class MyJavaScriptInterface
    {
        public void ProcessJavaScript(final String scriptname, final String args)
            {             
                mHandler.post(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                            {
                    String url="file:///android_asset/img.jpg";
                                webview.loadUrl("javascript:image(\""+url+"\")");
                            }
                    });
            }
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getimage()
 {
   Android.ProcessJavaScript("image",null); 
 }

function image(src) {
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = src;
    document.getElementById('image').appendChild(img);
}
</script>
```

and add the following,

```
<body onload="getimage()" >
```

**To pass more images:**

```
function image(src) {

        //var img = document.createElement("IMG");
        //img.src = src;
       // document.getElementById('image').appendChild(img);
            images = eval('(' + src+ ')');
            for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {    
            var img = document.createElement("IMG");
            img.src = images[i];            
              document.getElementById('image').appendChild(img);
            }
    }
```

and you pass String array instead of String in load url like

```
final class MyJavaScriptInterface
        {
            public void ProcessJavaScript(final String scriptname, final String args)
                {             
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run()
                                {
                        //String url="file:///android_asset/img.jpg";
                                    //webview.loadUrl("javascript:image(\""+url+"\")");
                                    ArrayList<String> url=new ArrayList<String>();
                                    url.add("file:///android_asset/img1.jpg");
                                    url.add("file:///android_asset/img2.jpg");
                                    url.add("file:///android_asset/img3.jpg");
                                    webview.loadUrl("javascript:image(\""+url+"\")");
                                }
                        });
                }
        }
```

**To call image script more times:**

```
  final class MyJavaScriptInterface
            {
                public void ProcessJavaScript(final String scriptname, final String args)
                    {             
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable()
                            {
                                public void run()
                                    {
                                      // you can load url anywhere in this application. check below to call this inside the other function.
                                       callimageFirstTime(scriptname,args);
                                     // check below to loadurl in other class Test.java
                                      Test newtest=new Test();
                                      newtest.methodtoloadurl(scriptname,args);
                                    }
                            });
                    }
            }

public void callimageFirstTime(String script, String arguments)
{
  // add images with String array and pass here
  webview.loadUrl("javascript:image(\""+url+"\")");

}
```

Comment: This was pretty helpful but could you explain how i might call use the function image multipule times in my onCreate method. As i see it right now the code you provided will load img.jpg once, but i want to stack multipule images ontop of each other, like a projection screen with markings on it.

Comment: see if you want to pass more images, then you can use String array instead of String

Comment: So in your code you invoke webview.loadurl(), but in the onCreate() you named it view, and it wasnt global. i tried using the code as is, but it didnt work, then i tried using the code with a global webview view, and that ran, but didnt seem to work.

Comment: No need to have webview as global, you can pass the webview to other classes as parameter. that's enough

Comment: Yeah but where? Eclipse is saying that 'webview' is undeclared Im just not sure where it gets passed through.

Comment: I will, i have an informal deadline(in the form of sterns looks) to meet so i went with a different method. But im interested in how this works because i figured out im going to have to use JInterfaces ether way. If your still willing to help i appreciate it, but its up to you. Ill post the relevent code in a pastebin, in a few hours.

Comment: If you have any doubt on this, ask question seperately

Comment: Im very very sorry, a lot of things have happened, and the whole club( thats what this is for) has fallen apart, so this project is only releavent in a personal sense anymore. This was very educational for me so i hope you dont feel as if its a waste of time, but the project is pretty much canceled. =/